# sending date range parameter from crystal to sql stored procedure

Tags: crystal-reports

is there a way(I think there is) to send date range parameter from crystal reports to a sql stored procedure? If so, how can I do it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create formulas to get min and max values from the range. create a subreport and use the stored procedure inside the subreport. Link the subreport parameters, which will be the SP parameters, to the formulas in the main report for min and max daterange values.

If you already have a subreport then you cannot use this method

Comment: I did that but the time I am adding the stored procedure to the subreport it asked me for date range parameters and at this time I do not have the option to link them to my main report parameters, I only have the option to leave them null or enter some values manually. What should I do then? @Lan